# How to increment the duration of a css animation in ngFor loop with ngStyle attribute

Tags: angular, css-animations, ng-style

I'd like to know if there is way to do this. I'm trying to increment the duration of a css animation. I couldn't find the right syntax to make it.
Thanks !

```
      <app-product *ngFor="let vetement of vetements; let i = index"

        [ngStyle]="{ 'animation': 'appear ease i*100 ms '}"

            title="{{vetement.title}}" 
             type="{{vetement.type}}" 
      description="{{vetement.description}}"
            price="{{vetement.price}}" 
         imageURL={{vetement.image}}>
  </app-product>
```

Comment: did you try animation-duration?

Comment: i*100ms is not doing it right because it is in a `string` format. Have you tried like: `'animation': 'appear ease ' + i * 100 + ' ms'`

Comment: Yes but still it's not working, I don't have any error but the page infinite loads

Answer (score 0):

Ok just found it, working like this :

```
 [ngStyle]="{ 'animation-duration' :  (i*100) + 'ms'}"
```